# Custom Select Component on Vue with SVG

Tags: vue.js, select, vue-component, tailwind-css

I'm creating a custom select component on Vue and I'm using tailwind to style it.

I would like to have an chevron-down caret svg align to the right, which will open the select options when clicked. I'm having some trouble with this.

```
<template>
  <div class="flex flex-wrap mb-4 relative">

    <select :value="value" @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)" class="w-full h-12 pl-4 bg-white focus:bg-grey-10 focus:text-grey-5 border-2 border-grey-9 rounded-lg text-sm focus:outline-none">
        <option :value="null">
          Select an option
        </option>
        <option v-for="option in options" :value="option.slug">{{ option.name }}</option>
    </select>

    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20" class="absolute mt-4 mr-4 right-0 cursor-pointer">
      <path d="M9.293 12.95l.707.707L15.657 8l-1.414-1.414L10 10.828 5.757 6.586 4.343 8z"/>
    </svg>


  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: [ 'value'],
    data () {
        return {
            options: [
                { slug: 'test1', name: 'Test 1' },
                { slug: 'test2', name: 'Test 2' },
            ],
        };
    },
  }
</script>
```

This is what it looks like, however the svg when clicked does not open the dropdown.

[image: Select image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the svg correctly? Take a look at this: https://codepen.io/herrfischer/pen/aNpWwy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the `<svg>` tag, you need to add the `.pointer-events-none` class. From the [Tailwind Docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/pointer-events/#app)

> Use .pointer-events-none to make an element ignore pointer events. The pointer events will still trigger on child elements and pass-through to elements that are "beneath" the target.

There is a helpful [custom select example](https://tailwindcss.com/components/forms/#custom-select) in the Tailwind docs.